# Why does Get-AzureStorageAccount give me different Endpoints than I see on the Azure Console?

Tags: azure, console

When I look out on my Storage Accounts on the Azure console I see the vendorsdiag220, but when I do a Get-AzureStorageAccount from PowerShell I see two different names, neither of which is vendorsdiag220.

Also, neither of the two names are listed on the Azure console.  What gives?

Comment: What "azure console" you are using old\new? are you using ARM\ASM? do you have multiple Azure subscriptions on your account? My guess is it has to do with ARM\ASM mix

Comment: It could be your storage account is a Resource Manager Storage Account, while the others are Service Management/Classic Storage Accounts, and will thus show when you run Get-AzureStorageAccount. Have you tried Add-AzureRmAccount followed by Get-AzureRmStorageAccount?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your storage account "vendorsdiag220" is an Azure Resource Manager type (ARM), which uses portal.azure.com. The Cmdlet you mentioned is for the classic portal which uses Azure Service Management (ASM) and is at manage.windowsazure.com

This is a link to the ARM version of the Cmdlet.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495134.aspx

You might have to get the latest version of Azure PowerShell. Here are some instructions if you do:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/